# Python Read Emails

Tags: c#, python, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

My teammate uses the above code in C# (.NET) to extract email details from his inbox. If you notice it does not require any credential.

```cs
    using System; 
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using System.Linq; 
    using System.Text; 
    using System.Threading.Tasks; 
    using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;    

    namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);

                service.AutodiscoverUrl("FirstName.LastName@company.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

                if (service != null)
                {
                    FindItemsResults<Item> resultout = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10));

                    foreach (Item item in resultout.Items)
                    {
                        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id);

                        String subject = message.Subject.ToString();
                        Console.Write(subject);

                        String fromwhom = message.From.Address.ToString();
                        Console.Write(fromwhom);                        
                    }    
                }            
            }

            private static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
            {
                // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
                bool result = false;
                Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);
                // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
                // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
                // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
                if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                return result;
            }
        } 
    }
```

I need to perform the same steps but in Python. i.e read email details.

My attempt

```
from exchangelib import Account, Configuration, Credentials, DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, NTLM
email = 'FirstName.LastName@company.com'
creds = Credentials(email, "")
account = Account(email, autodiscover=True, credentials = creds)
```

Error:

> AutoDiscoverFailed: All steps in the autodiscover protocol failed

With Autodiscover `false`

```
from exchangelib import Account, Configuration, Credentials, DELEGATE, IMPERSONATION, NTLM
email = 'FirstName.LastName@company.com'
creds = Credentials(email, "")
config = Configuration(server = "domain.com", credentials=creds)
account = Account(email, autodiscover=False, config = config)
```

Error:

> Wrong username or password for `https;//domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`

I can access the `https;//domain.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx` via url, without entering any credential.

Note: I am fairly good in Python with no knowledge of C#.

Comment: The C# version lost certainly requires authentication, but maybe it implicitly uses Windows SSO - possibly SSPI or Kerberos. exchangelib supports both.

Comment: In other words, you can check in Python if you can actually access the URL without credentials: `from requests import get; get('https://example.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx')`. If that fails, then some implicit auth is going on when you access the site in a browser.

Comment: The requests package gives me `<Response [401]>`. Will installing `pip install exchangelib[complete]` help?

Comment: I don't know if your system supports SSPI or Kerberos, but you can give it a try. Note the special setup needed to set up SSPI or Kerberos auth in exchangelib.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are different ways of approaching authentication in Python; here's [one](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/).

I've worked on a similar project, where I try to print out an email [web automation], for which I used selenium and a webdriver to access a yahoo mail. This project included page inspection -- [another](https://bitbucket.org/svf97/webauto/src/master/yahoo_email_retrieval.py) approach. The code isn't optimised and the final output is not what I intended yet, but you could understand the idea at least.

Good Luck!